# Copy objects in java referencing same object

Tags: java, copy

In java I have a object A which contain Object B and C and both B and C points to single object D .

Now I want to create a separate copy of A where in both B and C points to different copy of D.

Please help.

Comment: I really don't understand this. Please give an example.

Comment: You can make B and C to point to multiple objects(like a vector)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use composition. While building A, make it so that it has a B and a C as variables, and then on the constructor pass it a D instance, which in turn will be pointed to by B and C. Either this or what Frighi said.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a constructor in A object that take a A object as parameter.
Do the same thing in class D.

Then:

```
public class A {

    D b;
    D c;

    public A(A a) {
        this.b = new D(a.b);
        this.c = b;
    }
}


public class D {

    public D(D d) {
        // copy all d field to this
    }
}
```